# Error: uglifyjs not found

Tags: node.js, npm, minify, uglifyjs

I want to minify a folder automatically by a command line. I then installed `npm install -g minify-all`, then `minify-all /opt/myapp/`. It gives:

```
minify-all /opt/myapp/
found file: /opt/myapp/addin_online/css/Common.css
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/node_modules/node-minify/lib/node-minify.js:104
          throw new Error(bin + ' not found !');
          ^

Error: uglifyjs not found !
    at getPath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/node_modules/node-minify/lib/node-minify.js:104:17)
    at Object.compress (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/node_modules/node-minify/lib/node-minify.js:132:27)
    at Object.minify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/node_modules/node-minify/lib/node-minify.js:83:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:30:13
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:14:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at walk (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:10:36)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:16:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at walk (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:10:36)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Is `minify-all` the right package to use?

**Edit 1:** I tried `sudo npm install uglify-js -g`

```
/usr/local/bin/uglifyjs -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs
/usr/local/lib
└─┬ uglify-js@3.0.11 
  ├─┬ commander@2.9.0 
  │ └── graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
  └── source-map@0.5.6
```

And `sudo npm install uglify-js -save--dev` under `/opt/myapp/`

```
async@0.2.10 node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/async -> node_modules/swig/node_modules/async
flapper-news@0.0.0 /opt/myapp
├─┬ swig@1.4.2
│ └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.24 
│   └── source-map@0.1.34 
└─┬ uglify-js@3.0.11 
  ├─┬ commander@2.9.0 
  │ └── graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
  └── source-map@0.5.6
```

However, `minify-all /opt/myapp/` still shows:

```
found file: /opt/myapp/addin_online/css/Common.css
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/node_modules/node-minify/lib/node-minify.js:104
          throw new Error(bin + ' not found !');
          ^

Error: uglifyjs not found !
    at getPath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/node_modules/node-minify/lib/node-minify.js:104:17)
    at Object.compress (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/node_modules/node-minify/lib/node-minify.js:132:27)
    at Object.minify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/node_modules/node-minify/lib/node-minify.js:83:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:30:13
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:14:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at walk (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:10:36)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:16:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at walk (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/minify-all/index.js:10:36)
```

I don't have to use `uglify-js`, I just want to minimise `js` and `css`. Is there any other options?

Answer (score 11):

If you really use uglify, you need to go install `uglify-js`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js instead.

`npm install uglify-js -save--dev`

Comment: Please see my "Edit 1"

Comment: this works for minify-all error that op was talking about, should accept